# Boolean variable is not setting ,when reading firestore data

Tags: android

I am trying to read all the data on the `FireStore` database and if any document name matches, the boolean variable should be false , else it should be true. But the value of boolean variable is not changing.

```
public boolean checkUsername(EditText editText){
    final boolean[] flag = {false};
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(editText.getText().toString());
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    flag[0] =false;
                    Log.d("", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    flag[0]=true;
                    Log.d("", "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
    return flag[0];


}
```

---

This is the `Firestore` Database

collection      Document

Users            jaypatel, jaypatel2212

If the edit text value is jaypatel2212 or jaypatel, then the boolean variable should be false else it should be true.

Comment: Reading from Firestore is asynchronous operation. You function checkUsername will return before Firestore task is completed. You need to adapt your logic, move code you need to run into CompletionListener and use callbacks instead of function.

Answer (score -1):

The value of boolean flag is not changing because you have declared it **final**.
Also there's no need to use array when you are always returning and changing the 0th element only.

Also return flag should be inside onComplete() function as reading data from firestore is asynchronous task so even before you could fetch data from firestore you are returning the default initialized value of flag. So the code should look like this:-

```
private boolean flag = false;

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    flag = false;
                    Log.d("", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    flag = true;
                    Log.d("", "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
          return flag;
        }
```

Comment: Yes but there is an error if i dont make  the flag one element array ,studio autohelp suggests to make it one element array or  there is an compiler error, as well as removing final didnt make any difference

Comment: As @dalija stated above in comment that reading from firestore is asynchronous operation, so before your code fetch data firestore you are returning the value of flag which is false by default. So you need to return the value of flag inside the scope of onComplete() function just after else block. `else{ } return flag; } //close of onComplete()`

Comment: **There is no way you can return function value from asynchronous completion handler**. This answer is wrong and it will never work. It suffers from the same problem as original question. OP cannot use function, it must either directly implement appropriate code inside completion handler, or pass another completion handler to the method and call that handler within Firestore completion handler.